# Is it possible that a SELECT query is inserting data in Joomla DB?

Tags: php, mysql, select, joomla, joomla2.5

I need to check whether a value is in a DB. I am using

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery( true );

$query->select($db->quoteName('id'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__tablename'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('fieldname') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName($valuetocheck));
$db->setQuery($query);
$id = $db->loadResult();

echo "value = " . $id;

if($id) {/*action if the value already exists*/} else {/*...*/}
```

The problem is that every new value that I set to `$valuetocheck` is actually being inserted into the table. If I set a value that does not exist yet, it gets inserted, and so I always get a valid `$id` and cannot proceed to the `else {}`.

Is that possible? Is there any workaround to check whether a value is already inside?

Comment: Try printing the `$query` before this line `$db->setQuery($query);` and see what you get. If it is select query then it won't insert data for sure.

Comment: the query will **not** insert any values and you have specifically used `select`. Value are probably being inserted by another query somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

A `SELECT` query never insert any value to the DB If the data's are inserting in the table its should be somewhere else. Also instead of checking `$id` value you can check `numrows` as below.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery( true );

$query->select($db->quoteName('id'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__tablename'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('fieldname') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName($valuetocheck));
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
if($db->getNumRows() >0){
 //Data found
}
else{
 //Nod Data found
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Seems that using `$db->getNumRows()` is working better. Anyway, I get a warning because it is missing an argument, but it is not that important.
One more thing, `$db->quoteName` is escaping emails weirdly, turning user@host.com into `'user@host'.'com'`... is there any other quotation method for emails?

Comment: try $db->escape() instead of $db->quoteName(), warning may you missed $db->query(); after set query.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Any chance the db object gets reused differently in the code below?

1. Try to add `die('test 1');` just before the code you showed us and run to make sure for yourself that the table does not get changed. Don't mind that the website doesn't show anything.
2. Then move the die-command to just after the echo-command and run again. There is in my mind no way valuetocheck has entered the table at this stage. Check!
3. Continue testing when valuetocheck gets inserted..

Godo luck!